# Remove Content and Frame layout guides from UIScrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I made a pod Xcode 11 and iOS 13, created an UIScrollview and set my content there.

While installing on an older main project, this alert message shows:

> Content and frame layout guides before iOS 11.0

I can see the said layout guides in Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder layout guides]

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Simply uncheck the Content Layout Guides.

This option is found under the Size Inspector tab in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: This option is found under the **Size Inspector** tab in storyboard.

Comment: How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 10):

Uncheck "Content Layout Guides" on the scroll view.

Select ScrollView -> Property size inspector -> At the foot of the top-most Scroll View section (XCode 11.3.1)